# How to expire a password? (For inital account creation)

Tags: password, administration

I've often created temporary passwords for users for my own development machine for initial id creation.

For other environments, I've seen admins have the ability to have a password show as expired immediately, forcing me to change my password on first login.

How does one do this? 
(In this specific case I am using RHEL, but I'm hoping this information is universal across all/most linux distros)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the command

```
chage -d 0 [username]
```

to change the users expiration date, forcing them to change their password on first log in.

You can read more about it in the man pages for `chage` and `usermod`.

Answer (score 11):

There is a switch for passwd, -e. From the manpage (man passwd):

> -e, --expire
>          Immediately expire an accounts password. This in effect can force a user to change his/her password
>          at the users next login.

So

```
 sudo passwd -e LOGIN
```

should do it.

From the comments, I know that there is more variation than what I expected. So this is an Xubuntu 10.04 installation, and this is, what `file` reports:

```
file $(which passwd)
/usr/bin/passwd: setuid ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

Comment: Interesting, my `passwd` doesn't have this option. I will still note this as well though. Which linux distro did this passwd come from?

Comment: You're right. I way too often forget to mention what I'm using. I added more information.